# A test class fails : Formulas don't return any value when multiple test methods run on Dev Console

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, failing-tests

**Apex Test Class Setting**

The class is marked as @isTest(isParallel=false).
All the methods are static.

**Apex Class & Formula Setting**

The handler class is processed after insert.
The formulas return their values when other fields which are mentioned in the formulas are input.

**Issue**

I tried the same test method2 indivisualy and with method1 which has  similer composition.
I figured out formulas don't return any value and fail when test2 runs with test1 but return the values and pass when it runs individually.
Additionally, test1 passes(the formulas return correct values) when test2 runs with test1,so I guess the method which runs first works and the latter one doesn't work for some reasons.

```
static testMethod void additional_field_test1(){

        Case ca = new Case();
        ca.OS_Temp_ServiceAssignmentID__c = '10';
        ca.OS_Temp_UserId__c = CL_MailBatch_TestDataFactory.USER_ID;
        ca.OS_Temp_MailSendFlg__c = true;
        ca.OS_Temp_LastName__c = 'test';
        ca.OS_Temp_FirstName__c = 'taro';
        ca.SuppliedEmail = 'test@test.com';
        ca.JobCategory__c = '08';
        ca.Purpose__c = '10';
       
        Test.startTest();
        insert ca;
        Test.stopTest();
            
         List<MailInfoHistory__c> oInfoHisList = [SELECT Id,OS_ServiceMailSendFlg__c,OS_LastName__c,OS_FirstName__c, OS_MailAddress__c,JobCategory__c,Purpose__c, OS_ContractNo__c FROM MailInfoHistory__c ];

         System.assertEquals(ca.OS_Temp_MailSendFlg__c, oInfoHisList.get(0).OS_ServiceMailSendFlg__c);
         System.assertEquals(ca.OS_Temp_LastName__c, oInfoHisList.get(0).OS_LastName__c);
         System.assertEquals(ca.OS_Temp_FirstName__c, oInfoHisList.get(0).OS_FirstName__c);
         System.assertEquals(ca.SuppliedEmail, oInfoHisList.get(0).OS_MailAddress__c);
         System.assertEquals(‘formula_value1’, oInfoHisList.get(0).JobCategory__c);
         System.assertEquals('formula_value2’, oInfoHisList.get(0).Purpose__c);
    }  
   
   
   
static testMethod void additional_field_test2(){

        Case ca = new Case();
        ca.OS_Temp_ServiceAssignmentID__c = '10';
        ca.OS_Temp_UserId__c = CL_MailBatch_TestDataFactory.USER_ID;
        ca.OS_Temp_MailSendFlg__c = true;
        ca.OS_Temp_LastName__c = 'test';
        ca.OS_Temp_FirstName__c = 'taro2';
        ca.SuppliedEmail = 'test2@test.com';

        ca.JobCategory__c = '08';
        ca.Purpose__c = '10';

        Test.startTest();
        insert ca;
        Test.stopTest();

        List<Contact> contactList = [SELECT Id,SendML_telecom__c,LastName,FirstName, Email ,JobCategory__c,Purpose__c FROM Contact order by CreatedDate desc];
        System.assertEquals(ca.OS_Temp_MailSendFlg__c, contactList.get(0).SendML_telecom__c);
        System.assertEquals(ca.OS_Temp_LastName__c, contactList.get(0).LastName);
        System.assertEquals(ca.OS_Temp_FirstName__c, contactList.get(0).FirstName);
        System.assertEquals(ca.SuppliedEmail, contactList.get(0).Email);
        System.assertEquals(‘formula_value1’, contactList.get(0).JobCategory__c);
        System.assertEquals(‘formula_value2’, contactList.get(0).Purpose__c);      
    }
```

The custom object 'MailInfoHistory__c' is a junction object which transfers 'JobCategory__c' and 'Purpose__c' to Contact's fileds of the same name.
The formulas accept the number '08' '10' and return the text values 'formula_value1' and'formula_value2'

Comment: If possible can you please share your test class so we can check what the exact issue is?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.